# Error: no match for 'operator>>' in 'std::cin

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I'm back with another probably noob question. xP

So I have this at the moment.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string input;

    int man;

    cout<<"Choose your Character- 1.Sven or 2.Macy: ";
    cin>>input;
    cin.ignore();

    if ( input == "Sven" ){
        cout<<"Welcome to CRPG, my good Sir!";
        return 0;
        cin>>"Sven starts his journey at the Forest of Despair. At the beginning of the path, a fork in the road sits in his way. Which path shall you take? L or R?";
    }

    else if ( input == "Macy" ){
        cout<<"Girls cant fight, go back: ";
    }
}
```

Yes,  I have seen and read other posts about this same problem, but none seemed to apply to me. So what's a way I could fix this?

Comment: First, `#include <string>` if you want to use `std::string`. Second, what does it mean to read into a string literal (dead code, but wrong anyway)?

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is this line of code:

```
cin>>"Sven starts his journey at the Forest of Despair. <blah blah blah>";
```

Of course, `cin` doesn't offer an `operator>>` so the code fails to compile with the error message you describe. But assume, for a second, that it did provide such an operator. What would  your code mean then? You are trying to read something *into* a string literal (that is, something of type `const char[N]` where `N` is the length of the string) which is constant and cannot be modified.

Since you want to *write* something to the output (instead of reading something from the input) you ought to use `cout <<` instead.

Also note that you have a `return 0` which will prevent the statement from executing, since execution of `main` will stop once that statement is encountered.

---

**Update**: per the comments, please note that you did not `#include <string>` despite the fact that you do use `std::string` in your program. While you may be able to get away with this, you shouldn't rely on this behavior and you should explicitly include what you use. Failing to do so can, as Slava and MooingDuck suggested, can result in errors similar to what you reported.

Comment: Missing #include <string> could be culprit as well (may compile fine on some compilers though)

Comment: Doubtful. He would have gotten an error earlier, when he declares `string input`.

Comment: @NikBougalis: `<iostream>` needs the definition of `std::string`, so in MSVC `<iostream>` effectively defines `std::string`, but does _not_ include the `operator<<(istream,string)` and similar functions, resulting in exactly the error described: http://rextester.com/HSCBI33023

Comment: Interesting. I learned something new. Thanks @MooingDuck!

Answer (score 2):

You have to include header `<string>`

```
#include <string>
```

This header contains the declaration of `operator >>` for objects of type `std::string`

Also in this statement

```
   cin>>"Sven starts his journey at the Forest of Despair. At the beginning of the path, a fork in the road sits in his way. Which path shall you take? L or R?";
```

you have a typo. There should be `cout <<` instead of `cin >>`

Answer (score 1):

You used cin correctly in this case:

```
cin>>input;
cin.ignore();
```

Why not do the same here too?

```
string direction 
cout << "Sven starts his journey at the Forest of Despair. At the beginning of the path, a fork in the road sits in his way. Which path shall you take? L or R?";
cin >> direction

//do whatever you want to do with direction
```

EDIT:

why do you have

```
return 0;
```

This does not let the program do anything after this line because you are returning here.

Comment: Great spot of the `return 0` thing. My eyes scanned right past that and to the `cin` below!